# Factorizing assistance in controller logic that I think can be factorized

Tags: laravel, controller

Kindly assist in factorizing the below code($validatedAttributes). I feel I'm repeating myself with a lot of code. Newbie in laravel trying to implement DRY practice...

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $validatedAttributes = $request->validate([
            'condition' => 'required',
            'make' => 'required | alpha',
            'model' => 'required | string',
            'year' => 'required | numeric',
            'price' => 'required | numeric' ,
            'filenames' => 'required',
            'filenames.*' => 'image',

           'engineSize' => 'required | numeric',
            'numberSeats' => 'required | numeric',
            'mileage' => 'required | numeric',
            'power' => 'required | numeric',
            'doors' => 'required | numeric',
            'fuel' => 'required | alpha',
            'gearbox' => 'required | alpha',
            'color' => 'required | alpha',

            'description1' => 'required | string',
            'description2' => 'required | string',
            'description3' => 'required | string',
            'description4' => 'required | string',
            'description6' => 'required | string',
            'description7' => 'required | string',
            'description8' => 'required | string',
            'description9' => 'required | string',
            'description10' => 'required | string',
            'description11' => 'required | string',
            'description12' => 'required | string',

        ]);


        $files = [];
        if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().rand(1,100).'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(public_path('files'), $name);
                $files[] = $name;
            }
        }




        $vehicle = new Vehicle();
        $vehicle->condition = $request->input('condition');

        $vehicle->make = $request->input('make');
        $vehicle->model = $request->input('model');
        $vehicle->year = $request->input('year');
        $vehicle->price = $request->input('price');
        $vehicle->filenames= $files;
        $vehicle->engineSize = $request->input('engineSize');
        $vehicle->numberSeats = $request->input('numberSeats');
        $vehicle->mileage = $request->input('mileage');
        $vehicle->power = $request->input('power');

       
        $vehicle->doors = $request->input('doors');
        $vehicle->fuel = $request->input('fuel');
        $vehicle->gearbox = $request->input('gearbox');
        $vehicle->color = $request->input('color');

        $vehicle->description1 = $request->input('description1');
        $vehicle->description2 = $request->input('description2');
        $vehicle->description3 = $request->input('description3');
        $vehicle->description4 = $request->input('description4');
        $vehicle->description5 = $request->input('description5');
        $vehicle->description6 = $request->input('description6');
        $vehicle->description7 = $request->input('description7');
        $vehicle->description8 = $request->input('description8');
        $vehicle->description9 = $request->input('description9');
        $vehicle->description10 = $request->input('description10');
        $vehicle->description11 = $request->input('description11');
        $vehicle->description12 = $request->input('description12');



        $vehicle->save();


        return redirect(route('vehicles.create'))->with('flash', 'Vehicle Post Created 
        Successfully');
    }
```

I tried the below code after the `@foreach loop logic` but it's not working.

```
Vehicle::create($validatedAttributes);
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated, been trying to factorize it and I don't seem to get around it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [mass assigment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)**

First of all you need to define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable:

In your Vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'condition',
      'make',
     //...
     //...
      'description11'
      'description12'
    ];
}
```

Alternatively you can specify which attributes you don not want to be mass assignable:

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];
}
```

After that you can create a model in your controller method (or anywhere else) like:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::create( $request->all() );
```

**Use [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)**

First of all you need to create a request:

```
php artisan make:request StoreVehicleRequest
```

This command will create a form request class which will be placed in the `app/Http/Requests` directory.

Open that file and move your validation code there:

```
class StoreVehicleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; //Check the laravel documentation about this. 
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'condition' => 'required',
            'make' => 'required | alpha',
            //...
            //...
            'description11' => 'required | string',
            'description12' => 'required | string',
        ];
    }
}
```

After that type-hint the request on your controller method:

```
public function store(StoreVehicleRequest $request)
{
  //code...
}
```

**Use [file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads)**

You can simplify your file storing code:

```
$request->file('file_input_name')->store('folder/path');
```

---

**If you did these things, your method will be much more readable:**

```
public function store(StoreVehicleRequest $request)
{

    $files = [];
    if($request->hasFile('filenames'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file){
          $files[] = basename($file->store('files'));
        }
    }

    $vehicle = Vehicle::create( $request->all() );
    $vehicle->filenames = $files;
    $vehicle->save();

    return redirect(route('vehicles.create'))->with('flash', 'Vehicle Post Created 
    Successfully');
}
```

---

**Note that I did not test the code, there may be errors in it!**

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is create a request class with
php artisan make:request VehicleRequest
Then do your validation there dont forget to put authorize to true
Then inject tha class (VehicleRequest $request)
And just go with Vehicle::create($request->validated())